# C# : Better way to code this?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a block of code to handle exceptions in my application, which uses an if/else block to obtain the message content.
My code is as follows:

```
// define variable to hold exceptions...
var exceptionMessage = new StringBuilder();  
// based on the exception type...  
if (expType == typeof(EntityValidationException))  
{  
    // append the relevant message to the text...  
    exceptionMessage.Append(exception.InnerException.Message);  
}  
else if (expType == typeof(ValidationException))  
{  
    // This is the type of error generated when entities are validated  
    var validationException = (ValidationException)exception;  
    exceptionMessage.Append(validationException.InnerException.Message);  
}  
else if (expType == typeof(DomainSecurityException))  
{  
    // These are security breaches  
    var domainSecurityException = (DomainSecurityException)exception;  
    exceptionMessage.Append(domainSecurityException.InnerException.Message);  
}  
else if (expType == typeof(DomainInternalMessageException))  
{  
    // These are the type of errors generated a System.Exception occurs and is  
    // converted by the exception handling policy to a more friendly format  
    var domainInternalMessageException = (DomainInternalMessageException)exception;  
    exceptionMessage.Append(domainInternalMessageException.ExceptionMessage);  
}
else  
{  
    exceptionMessage.AppendFormat(ErrorMessagesRes.Standard_Error_Format, "Unknown error", exception.InnerException.Message);   
}  
// this shows the message as an alert popup...  
this.DisplayJavascriptMessage(exceptionMessage.ToString());
```

This has been improved from the original version, but just want to see if there is a neater, more re-usable solution to this code.
Thanks in advance
Martin

Comment: Why don't you `switch()` your `expType`? This would bring a litte more structure into your code.

Comment: I tried that but you can't use switch with non itegral types, which was why i hadn't used that structure.

Comment: @Martin: You cannot `switch` on `Type`s.

Comment: @m.edmondson - what is not correct? that you can't switch on non-integral types?

Comment: @Martin S - Sorry I read it wrong, thought you put integer types :-)

Comment: You could switch on typeof(Exception).ToString thought.

Comment: @m.edmondson - I did, but realised and changed it, so no need for sorry :)

Comment: @David Mårtensson - tried that and couldn't get that to work either.

Comment: I would add a null check on all those `InnerExceptions`.

Comment: There is one already at the head of the procedure:  <code>  // if exceptiopn not found...  
if (exception == null)  
{  
// simply redirected to a new page...  
return;  
}  </code>

Comment: what if `exception` is not null, and `exception.InnerException` is null?

Comment: @SWeko - yes, hadn't considered that. I only added the inner exception call because I kept getting no text from the exception Message property.

Comment: string messageText = exception.InnerException == null ? exception.Message : exception.InnerException.Message;

Comment: Actually, we have a site for this kind of question:  codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that this is a routine which gets passed an exception object (and is not directly involved in a try catch block) and assuming the "exception" object derives eventually from Exception, you could concise your code a bit to do

```
// define variable to hold exceptions...
            var exceptionMessage = new StringBuilder();

            // based on the exception type...  
            if (exception is EntityValidationException || exception is ValidationException || exception is DomainSecurityException)
            {
                // append the relevant message to the text...  
                exceptionMessage.Append(exception.InnerException.Message);
            }

            else if (expType == typeof(DomainInternalMessageException))
            {
                // These are the type of errors generated a System.Exception occurs and is  
                // converted by the exception handling policy to a more friendly format  
                var domainInternalMessageException = (DomainInternalMessageException)exception;
                exceptionMessage.Append(domainInternalMessageException.ExceptionMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                exceptionMessage.AppendFormat(ErrorMessagesRes.Standard_Error_Format, "Unknown error", exception.InnerException.Message);
            }
            // this shows the message as an alert popup...  
            this.DisplayJavascriptMessage(exceptionMessage.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    var exceptionMessage = new StringBuilder();  

    try
    {
    }
    catch(EntityValidationException exc)
    {  
        exceptionMessage.Append(exc.InnerException.Message);  
    }  
    catch(ValidationException exc)  
    {  
        exceptionMessage.Append(exc.InnerException.Message);  
    }  
    ....
```

Make sure the catch blocks come in proper order from least generic to most generic.

Comment: It's for a web application, and we want to handle the errors, pass the exception message to a log file, and show a simple error page, rather than the application bomb out with a error stack. It works, but whilst reviewing the code, i wondered if it could be improved.

Comment: @thecoop - the code in question doesn't show what is being thrown

Comment: The original exception source should be wrapped with this try block.

Comment: @Jukub Konecki - thaks, but the exception is being passed in, so the try/catch block won't work. I'm using the exception to log and convert it to a friendlier message.

Comment: @Jukub Konecki - Sorry. At present, each aspx page event uses a try/catch block, and any exceptions are passed to this procedure. This then attempts to find out the type and get the message details. I don't want to change the way it handles as we are too far into development now, but am just trying to make the code more readable and re-usable going forward. Thanks for all the suggestions so far.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static Exception On<T>(this Exception e, Action<T> action)
{
    if(e is T)
        action((T)e);

    return e;
}

exception.
    On<ValidationException>(e => exceptionMessage.Append(e.InnerException.Message)).
    On<DomainInternalMessageException>(e => ...);
```

Comment: @Martin S: Make that `On` method a member of some static class and rewrite your exception handling code with this big-ass chain of method calls.

Comment: OK, but I get an error trying to cast expression of type 'System.Exception' to type 'T' with the on method.

Comment: I've tried to implement @Anton's code, but get the cast error in the method; am unsure how to handle where I want to do more than just append to a stringbuilder object within the On method, and also can I simply pass On<Exception> into the chain to deal with the else?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever i see those `if else if` statements i think this must be done easier. In some cases the switch statement can help, but as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711005/why-doesnt-c-switch-statement-allow-using-typeof-gettype) already stated, it is not possible to switch on Type.

So another workaround i commonly use is some kind of `Dictionary<Type, something>`. Where `something` depends on what i'd like to do. The maybe best matching construct for your case would something like `Dictionary<Type, Func<Exception, string>>` which could be used in your case something like this:

```
Dictionary<Type, Func<Exception, string>> _FunctorsForType;

private void InitializeFunctorsForType()
{
    _FunctorsForType = new Dictionary<Type, Func<Exception, string>>();

    // Add a normal function
    _FunctorsForType.Add(typeof(ArgumentException), (Func<Exception, string>)ForArgumentException);

    // Add as lambda
    _FunctorsForType.Add(typeof(InvalidCastException), (ex) =>
        {
            // ToDo: Whatever you like
            return ex.Message;
        });
}

private string ForArgumentException(Exception ex)
{
    var argumentException = ex as ArgumentException;

    if (argumentException == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Exception must be of type " + typeof(ArgumentException).Name);
    }

    // ToDo: Whatever you like
    return ex.Message;
}

private void Usage(Type type)
{
    Func<Exception, string> func;

    if (!_FunctorsForType.TryGetValue(type, out func))
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Exception type " + type.Name + " is not supported.");
    }

    var message = func(new NullReferenceException());

    // ToDo: Whatever you have to do with your message
}
```

So with this construction you don't have to put all your intelligence into a big if-else statement. Instead you can put them in separate functions (maybe in different classes) to get a better organization of how to handle each type you like to support.

Answer (score 0):

```
string exceptionMessage;
if (expType == typeof(EntityValidationException) || 
    expType == typeof(ValidationException) ||
    expType == typeof(DomainSecurityException))
  exceptionMessage = exception.InnerException.Message;
else if (expType == typeof(DomainInternalMessageException))  
 exceptionMessage = ((DomainInternalMessageException)exception).ExceptionMessage;
else  
 exceptionMessage = string.Format(ErrorMessagesRes.Standard_Error_Format, "Unknown error", exception.InnerException.Message);  

this.DisplayJavascriptMessage(exceptionMessage);
```

A little compressed, and without comments.

Comment: Thanks, a simpler version of what I am doing. Am going to look at Anton's reply first.

Comment: Thanks all - I will go away and review the options. Apprecite your time and help.