# Why is this switch on type case considered confusing?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I was looking for a way to refactor and simplify one function where I have to do data sorting depending on input class type, and got stuck at `switch(input.GetType()):`

Quick search led me to [Why doesn't C# switch statement allow using typeof/GetType()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711005/why-doesnt-c-switch-statement-allow-using-typeof-gettype) with a link to http://blogs.msdn.com/peterhal/archive/2005/07/05/435760.aspx

I read the documentation, but I don't get the justification that the situation is confusing.

From the article:

> Unfortunately, like many 'simple'
>   language features, type switch is not
>   as simple as it first appears. The
>   troubles start when you look at a more
>   significant, and no less important,
>   example like this:

```
class C {}
interface I {}
class D : C, I {}

switch typeof(e) {
case C: ... break;
case I: ... break;
default: ... break;
}
```

What's not simple about it? The call `typeof(e)` cannot return - this is a `I` `D` and `C`. It has to return a `Type` not an array of interface and class types - `Type[]`. So the type of the `class D` is `D`. And `D` corresponds to a `default:` branch.

An I missing something?

Comment: see also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156467/switch-pattern-matching-idea
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252186/switch-case-on-type-c-sharp
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542793/how-to-use-switch-case-on-a-type
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478464/c-sharp-switch-on-type
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298976/c-sharp-is-there-a-better-alternative-than-this-to-switch-on-type

Comment: and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94305/what-is-quicker-switch-on-string-or-elseif-on-type
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947343/how-to-switch-between-possible-type-of-an-object
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115028/best-way-to-switch-behavior-based-on-type
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551773/c-sharp-which-is-the-best-alternative-to-switch-on-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you don't expect the switch to match on subclasses. But this would break the Liskov Substitution Principle. (where if you passed in a C object, the code would work, but not with a D, even though D is a subclass of C).

Comment: Yes, because we are not branching on class, we are branching on typeof(class) which is a single, well defined value, just like a regular int. You don't branch on value 32 to a different branch if it's defined as (int32)32 or (int64)32.

Comment: The principle is a good read though. And I guess someone can break the app by changing class D to it's subclass under some circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a perfectly valid argument on Peter Hallam's blog post that you don't expect `switch` statement to differ if you reorder things, so it's really only useful if only one branch can be valid at the same time, whereas with `Type` one class is always multiple different types along the inheritance chain.

No one stops you from doing this with an if...else chain, where you do expect it to be evaluated in the order you put things.

Comment: But it would not differ, because in both cases only default branch would be considered. type is D, it's not a set of types, so there is no way that branch I or C could be executed. You would have to cast the class to C to get branch C. Kind of - ((ClassC)input).GetType().

Comment: No, D is also a C and I (and Object), any class is also a valid type of any of its ancestors up on the inheritance chain.

Comment: Of course you could structure your statements that it goes from the higher level / more concrete class definitions to more generic ones, but the point is that this ordering shouldn't be a requirement to do so when working with `switch`, but you can do it with if...else where it's expected that the conditions get evaluated in order and until the first match is found.

Comment: But it's type is D, unless it's cast to a different object. We are not switching on class. Although they can be valid types, you wouldn't expect string a; a.GetType(); to return Object. You would if you'd have performed a cast though.

Comment: Well `typeof` or `Object.GetType()` returns a `System.Type` which is probably compared on a less strict basis, as in returning true even for inherited types. You could try comparing `Type.FullName` for example if you want it to be stricter.