# c# unknown input parameter type?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic function `static Log<T>(T Log)`. I would like to check type of `T` and decide what to do next.

This is what I got so far:

```
public static void Log<T>(T log)
{
    switch (typeof(log))
    { ... }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? My error is that typeof(log) doesnt work.

Comment: What is your error - we are not mind readers.

Comment: switch expects integral type!

Comment: I think he ask what to write inside the swich. Am I right?

Comment: @Reniuz - No, it doesn't. It just needs to be an expression.

Comment: Yes, but I'am just noting all who suggesting to change from `typeof` to `GetType()`.

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708911/using-case-switch-and-gettype-to-determine-the-object

Comment: switch does not work with System.Type. "A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
switch (expression)
{

}
```

`expression` = An integral or string type expression (From MSDN)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=vs.71).aspx

The `typeof` keyword returns neither of these. You can't use `log.GetType()` as you need to meet the criteria above of which `Type` isn't suitable.

To be on the safe side I would limit this to `if` statements with the corresponding types as this will achieve the same thing.

```
static void a<T>(T b)
{
  if (typeof(T) == typeof(B))
    Console.WriteLine("T is B");
  else if(typeof(T) == typeof(C))
    Console.WriteLine("T is C");
}
```

EDIT:

If you have for arguments sake you have:

```
  public class Vehicle 
  {
    public virtual int MoveVehicle() 
    {
       //Do Logic
       return 0;
    }
  }
  public class Car : Vehicle { }
```

And you want a generic method to move the Vehicle you could do something called `generic type constraints`

```
static void a<T>(T b) where T : Vehicle
{
    int newPosition = b.MoveVehicle();
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx

T has to be a Vehicle now, so you have access to the methods in Vehicle. You can pass a car to the method and it will still be able to call the `MoveVehicle` method.

```
  a<Vehicle>(new Car());
```

Comment: And if I would want to call some function on T how could I do this? lets say I have class car and people both support whoAmI function, could I call b.whoAmI() inside this generic function ???

Comment: @gr33x93 See my edit and check if this suffices what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

You need to ask the typeof `T` not `log` - and a switch must be on a primitive type (or a `string`) so look at the type `Name` or perhaps `FullName`

`switch(typeof(T).Name){...}`

you could also call `GetType` on the instance of `T`:

`switch(log.GetType().Name){...}`

Both would yield the same result

Comment: Of course String is not primitive! :-) It's just a C# compiler feature. The compiler is actually replace the switch on the string with a dictionary ( Like in my answer ) which has a int as value and does a switch on the int.

Comment: @FelixK. Fixed (for the pedants out there ;))

Answer (score 2):

use `GetType` function

```
  switch(log.GetType().ToString()) {....}
```

insted of  `typeof().`

Comment: -1 Won't work, `System.Type` isn't a integral type so it won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

You cannot make a switch on a `System.Type` and also you cannot do a `typeof` on a variable.
What you can do is this:

```
static Dictionary<Type, TypeEnum> Types = new Dictionary<Type, TypeEnum>() { { typeof(TypeA), TypeEnum.TypeA } }; // Fill with more key-value pairs

enum TypeEnum
{
    TypeA
    // Fill with types
}


public static void Log<T>(T log)
{
    TypeEnum type;
    if (Types.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out type)) {
        switch (type)
        { ... }
    }
}
```

It's also the fastest solution which i know. Dictionary lookups are very fast. You could also do this with a `System.String` ( via `Type.Name` or `Type.FullName` ) but it'll be slower because the string methods for `Equals` ( sure ) and for `GetHashCode` ( depending on their implementation ) are slower.

When you would use a String instead, it's the same what the compiler does when working with switch on a String.

```
switch(typeof(T).FullName) // Converted into a dictionary lookup
{ ... }
```

### More thoughts

Depending on what you want to archive you should know that you also can use constraints:

```
public interface ILogItem
{
    String GetLogData();
    LogType LogType { get; }
}

public void Log<T>(T item) 
    where T : ILogItem
{
    Debug.WriteLine(item.GetLogData());
    // Read more data
    switch (item.LogType)
    { ... }
}
```