# What is the best method for handling FaultExceptions in Async WCF calls?

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I'm calling a WCF service from a Silverlight client, therefore making all the calls async.

When the WCF service returns an ExceptionFault, the error object gets populated in the arguments to the Completed event handler...

```
proxy.UpdateCompleted += (o, e) =>
 {
     if(e.Error != null)
            .... do something
 }
```

what is the best approach for converting e.Error into a FaultException?

```
if (e.Error is FaultException<InvalidOperationFault>)
{
  var fault = e.Error as FaultException<InvalidOperationFault>;    
  ... do something
}
```

or

```
try
{
   throw e.Error
}
catch(FaultException<InvalidOperationFault> fault)
{
   ... do something
}
```

or can you suggest anything better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer the second option, to throw e.Error if it is not null. That way the resulting code is structured the same as in the synchronous method invocation case:

```
try
{
  if ( e.Error != null ) 
    throw e.Error;
  // ...
}
catch ( FaultException<ValidationFault> fault ) { /* ... */ }
catch ( FaultException<MyServiceFault> fault ) { /* ... */ }
// ...
finally { /* ... * }
```

Comment: I have a concern that this technique may change the stack trace to make it appear that the exception came from the point of the `throw`.

Answer (score 0):

This just boils down to the lack of Switch on type support in C#

[Is there a better alternative than this to 'switch on type'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298976/c-is-there-a-better-alternative-than-this-to-switch-on-type)