# Xamarin - Exception handling in WCF async callback not working - App crash

Tags: ios, wcf, asynchronous, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm working on an **iOS** app using **Xamarin**, and this app makes **async calls** to a **WCF** webservice, with the proxy being generated using the SilverLight SlSvcutil tool, as recommended by Xamarin team.

**The problem is:** If the device is not connected to the internet and the app tries to make a call to the webservice, it crashes without catching the exception.

The code looks like this:

```
             int versao = 0;

            // Set callback function
            WebService.WSVersaoCompleted += (
                object sender, 
                WSVersaoCompletedEventArgs e) => {

                versao = e.Result;

                // Free thread
                syncEvent.Set();
            };

            // Webservice call
            WebService.WSVersaoAsync();

            // Hold thread
            syncEvent.WaitOne();

            return versao > 0;
```

So, i'm actually able to get a response, the app hits the "completed" event, and i can see that e.Result is a **System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException**, but even if i wrap the whole thing in a try/catch block, it always crashes.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i'm even a little embarassed, but i figured out that the EventArgs in the Completed event provides an Error property, which can be used to handle any problems.

[This thread helped me on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366798/what-is-the-best-method-for-handling-faultexceptions-in-async-wcf-calls?rq=1)

Anyway, i'm gonna leave it here for learning purposes, and in case someone else falls into the same problem.

Thank you all.