# Assignment in an if statement

Tags: c#, casting, if-statement

I have a class `Animal`, and its subclass `Dog`.
I often find myself coding the following lines:

```
if (animal is Dog)
{
    Dog dog = animal as Dog;    
    dog.Name;    
    ... 
}
```

For the variable `Animal animal;`.

Is there some syntax that allows me to write something like:

```
if (Dog dog = animal as Dog)
{    
    dog.Name;    
    ... 
}
```

Comment: None that I know of. Any reason not to move Name up to Animal?

Comment: Just a note, code like can often be the result of breaking one of the [SOLID Principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).  The [L - Liskov Substitution Principle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-the-liskov-substitution-principle).  Not saying it's wrong to do what you are doing all the time, but might be worth thinking about.

Comment: please take note of what @ckittel is doing, you probably don't want to do this

Comment: In some languages, including C#, I believe, `null` is cast to `false`.  So, if the result of the assignment is null, the statement evaluates to `null` which is then cast to `false`.  That is why in some languages you can use `if(var) {...}` to execute code only if that variable is non-null.  Generally, assigning to variables in an `if` statement is poo-pooed because it looks like a common error (typing `=` instead of `==`).  One used to be able to gain some (small) performance benefit from using an assignment in an `if` block, but many modern compilers will do optimizations like this for you.

Comment: Just a note: In PHP for instance you can do `if($var = <expression>)` and then `$var` is casted to `bool` and used for the check. `$var` is than also available in the scope where the `if` statement is.

Comment: @Solo no, `null` != `false` in C#; C# only allows actual bools or things implicitly convertible to bools in `if` conditions. Neither nulls nor any of the integer types are implicitly convertible to bools.

Comment: @romkyns thanks, I was hoping someone would correct me if I was wrong.  It's been a year and a half since I've done any C#... what I said is however generally true (e.g. in C/C++)

Comment: This is one of the (multiple) problems I have with C#. To avoid polluting the scope with a variable used only in the `if` clause, I wrap everything is a scope, which is more verbose, and almost as ugly than the `for(...)` solution of Jon Skeet, marked `EVIL EVIL EVIL` for some reason... Aaah, sweet Inquisition... ^_^ ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - Is there a better alternative than this to 'switch on type'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298976/c-sharp-is-there-a-better-alternative-than-this-to-switch-on-type)

Comment: And here we are with [C#7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/) and new syntax. I'm out of here though, time to learn native C++ and use a language with a more refined standard ^-^

Answer (score 380):

The answer below was written years ago and updated over time. As of C# 7, you can use pattern matching:

```
if (animal is Dog dog)
{
    // Use dog here
}
```

Note that `dog` is still in scope after the `if` statement, but isn't definitely assigned.

---

No, there isn't. It's more idiomatic to write this though:

```
Dog dog = animal as Dog;
if (dog != null)
{
    // Use dog
}
```

Given that "as followed by if" is almost *always* used this way, it might make more sense for there to be an operator which performs both parts in one go. This isn't currently in C# 6, but may be part of C# 7, if the [pattern matching proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/206) is implemented.

The problem is that you can't *declare* a variable in the condition part of an `if` statement<sup>1</sup>. The closest approach I can think of is this:

```
// EVIL EVIL EVIL. DO NOT USE.
for (Dog dog = animal as Dog; dog != null; dog = null)
{
    ...
}
```

That's just *nasty*... (I've just tried it, and it does work. But please, please don't do this. Oh, and you can declare `dog` using `var` of course.)

Of course you could write an extension method:

```
public static void AsIf<T>(this object value, Action<T> action) where T : class
{
    T t = value as T;
    if (t != null)
    {
        action(t);
    }
}
```

Then call it with:

```
animal.AsIf<Dog>(dog => {
    // Use dog in here
});
```

Alternatively, you could combine the two:

```
public static void AsIf<T>(this object value, Action<T> action) where T : class
{
    // EVIL EVIL EVIL
    for (var t = value as T; t != null; t = null)
    {
        action(t);
    }
}
```

You can also use an extension method without a lambda expression in a cleaner way than the for loop:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AsOrEmpty(this object value)
{
    T t = value as T;
    if (t != null)
    {
        yield return t;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
foreach (Dog dog in animal.AsOrEmpty<Dog>())
{
    // use dog
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> You can *assign* values in `if` statements, although I rarely do so. That's not the same as declaring variables though. It's not *terribly* unusual for me to do it in a `while` though when reading streams of data. For example:

```
string line;
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    ...
}
```

These days I normally prefer to use a wrapper which lets me use `foreach (string line in ...)` but I view the above as a pretty idiomatic pattern. It's *usually* not nice to have side-effects within a condition, but the alternatives usually involve code duplication, and when you know this pattern it's easy to get right.

Comment: One could write an `AsIf` extension (upon `object`) taking the destination type as a type paramater and an `Action<T>` parameter for the body which encapsulates the `as` conversion and null check. (`IfIs` might be a more accurate though less entertaining name.)

Comment: +1 for giving an answer and also begging that the OP doesn't use it.  Instant classic.

Comment: @Paul: I was just doing that, as it happens.

Comment: Why do you need the `t = null` in the final `for` clause? It should work just fine without it.

Comment: @jonp If you wanted to loop forever, sure.

Comment: @jonp: It's not intended to be an actual loop; without that clause, it'd run forever.

Comment: @jonp: It's to stop the loop after one iteration.

Comment: I'm not sold on the (ab)use of `for` here though.

Comment: @Paul: If I were trying to *sell* it to anyone, I wouldn't strongly advise them not to use it. I'm just showing what's *possible*.

Comment: @Paul: I think that may have been the motivation behind `EVIL EVIL EVIL`, but I'm not positive.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: Evil is never positive, unless you're playing Dungeon Keeper, in which case it's **gooooood**

Comment: Inspiring. I didn't even suspect that C# can get so close to C++ in terms of being evil.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: I didn't notice the edits when I wrote the comment. It's all very fluxating.

Comment: I made a similar extension method (with a bunch of overloads) a while ago and I called them `AsEither(...)`, I think it's a bit clearer than `AsIf(...)`, so I can write `myAnimal.AsEither(dog => dog.Woof(), cat => cat.Meeow(), unicorn => unicorn.ShitRainbows())`.

Comment: That's the best abuse of C# I've seen in a while. Clearly you are an evil genius.

Comment: @herzmeister Nice API. Could save a lot of boilerplate if you find yourself in a switch() very often!

Comment: @Eric: I feel deeply honoured - I can only imagine the horrific things the team must come up with at times :)

Comment: @Jon: The scary thing about this one is that I can actually imagine someone using it in production code.

Comment: +1 Jon for AsIf; from the unofficial fan club! of course, now I'm going to have to rewrite some of my production code with a Wayne's World variable naming scheme, just so I can figure out a way to use: `schyeah.AsIf` :D (wow, @Eric and Jon, both of you at the same time! [hmm.] anyway, just don't get too close to each other—don't want your reps to go prompt critical! :P) `isExcellent = xpert[0].AsIf<JonSkeet>(j => j.partyOn) && xpert[1].AsIf<EricLippert>(e => e.partyOn());` :D ♡

Comment: @Jons - It goes to say you could use `Dog dog; if ((dog = animal as Dog) != null) { ... }`. You still need two lines to do that though; so you might as well go for clarity.

Comment: @Jonathan: That still introduces the variable into the parent scope, which is what I believe the OP is trying to avoid. There's always "start a new block then" - but I think most of the time it's just fine to use the code at the top of my answer.

Comment: That kind of 0 or 1 collection looks very much like an Option pattern and is heavily (ab)used in Scala.

Comment: +1 lol.  I want to know when this hits production.  What have you done!?

Comment: Jon's `AsOrEmpty` is very nearly built-in: `foreach (var dog in new[] { animal }.OfType<Dog>())` - nothing evil about that :)

Comment: AsOrEmpty sounds like the OfType<>() extension method of System.Linq

Comment: @JonSkeet I would any day prefer a bool return type for `AsIf` :)

Comment: I've used things like that for loop snippet... in C macros. That's where all the hacks come out in my experience.

Answer (score 49):

If `as` fails, it returns `null`.

```
Dog dog = animal as Dog;

if (dog != null)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: First, thank you. Second, I want to create the dog variable in the scope of the `if` statement and not in outer scope.

Comment: @Michael you cannot do that in an if statement.  The if has to have a bool result not an assignment.  Jon Skeet provides some nice generic and lambda combinations you may which to consider as well.

Comment: `if` can have a bool result *and* an assignment. `Dog dog; if ((dog = animal as Dog) != null) { // Use Dog }` but that still introduces the variable in the outer scope.

Answer (score 13):

You **can** assign the value to the variable, as long as the variable already exists.  You can also scope the variable to allow that variable name to be used again later in the same method, if that is a problem.

```
public void Test()
{
    var animals = new Animal[] { new Dog(), new Duck() };

    foreach (var animal in animals)
    {
        {   // <-- scopes the existence of critter to this block
            Dog critter;
            if (null != (critter = animal as Dog))
            {
                critter.Name = "Scopey";
                // ...
            }
        }

        {
            Duck critter;
            if (null != (critter = animal as Duck))
            {
                critter.Fly();
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

assuming

```
public class Animal
{
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            Console.WriteLine("Name is now " + _name);
        }
    }
}

public class Duck : Animal
{
    public void Fly()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Flying");
    }
}
```

gets output:

```
Name is now Scopey
Flying
```

The pattern of variable assignment in the test is also used when reading byte blocks from streams, for example:

```
int bytesRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) 
{
    // ...
}
```

The pattern of variable scoping used above, however, is not a particularly common code pattern and if I saw it being used all over the place I'd be looking for a way to refactor it out.

Answer (score 13):

> Is there some syntax that allows me to write something like:

```
if (Dog dog = animal as Dog) { ... dog ... }
```

> ?

There likely will be in C# 6.0. This feature is called "declaration expressions".  See

https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/565640

for details.

The proposed syntax is:

```
if ((var i = o as int?) != null) { … i … }
else if ((var s = o as string) != null) { … s … }
else if ...
```

More generally, the proposed feature is that *a local variable declaration may be used as an expression*. This `if` syntax is just a nice consequence of the more general feature.

Comment: At a glance this seems less readable then just declaring the variable like you would today.  Would you happen to know why this particular feature has managed to pass the -100 point bar?

Comment: @asawyer: First, this is a very frequently requested feature. Second, other languages have this extension to "if"; gcc for example allows the equivalent in C++. Third, the feature is more general than just "if", as I noted. Fourth, there is a trend in C# since C# 3.0 to make more and more things that required a statement context instead require an expression context; this helps with functional-style programming. See the language design notes for more details.

Comment: @asawyer: You're welcome! Feel free to participate in the discussion on Roslyn.codeplex.com if you have more comments.  Also, I would add:  Fifth, the new Roslyn infrastructure lowers the marginal costs to the implementation team of doing these sorts of small experimental features, which means that the magnitude of the "minus 100" points is decreased. The team is taking this opportunity to explore perfectly decent small features that have been long-requested but never made it above the -100 point barrier previously.

Comment: Readers of these comments who are confused about what "points" we're talking about should read former C# designer Eric Gunnerson's blog post on this topic: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx.  This is an analogy; there are no actual "points" being counted up.

Comment: @asawyer: I think this feature really shines in calls to `Try*` (e.g., `TryParse`).  This feature not only makes such calls into a single expression (as they should be, IMO), but also allows for cleaner scoping of such variables.  I am enthusiastic about having the `out` parameter of a `Try` method be scoped to its conditional; this makes it harder to introduce certain types of bugs.

Comment: NOTE: it's 2020 (C# 9) and it's not possible to do `if ((var myLocal = myObj.myProp) != null ) { … myLocal … }`

Answer (score 9):

One of the extension methods I find myself writing and using often* is

```
public static TResult IfNotNull<T,TResult>(this T obj, Func<T,TResult> func)
{
    if(obj != null)
    {
        return func(obj);
    }
    return default(TResult);
}
```

Which could be used in this situation as

```
string name = (animal as Dog).IfNotNull(x => x.Name);
```

And then `name` is the dog's name (if it is a dog), otherwise null.

*I have no idea if this is performant. It has never come up as a bottleneck in profiling.

Comment: +1 for the note. If it has never come up as a bottleneck in profiling, that's a pretty good sign that it is *sufficiently* performant.

Comment: Why would you take the defaultValue as an argument and let the caller decide what it I z instead of falling back to default (....)?

Answer (score 5):

Going against the grain here, but maybe you're doing it wrong in the first place. Checking for an object's type is almost always a code smell. Don't all Animals, in your example, have a Name? Then just call Animal.name, without checking whether it's a dog or not.

Alternatively, invert the method so that you call a method on Animal that does something differently depending on the concrete type of the Animal. See also: Polymorphism.

Answer (score 4):

Shorter Statement

```
var dog = animal as Dog
if(dog != null) dog.Name ...;
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem (with the syntax) is *not* with the assignment, as the assignment operator in C# is a valid expression. Rather, it is *with the desired declaration* as declarations are statements.

If I must write code like that I will sometimes (depending upon the larger context) write the code like this:

```
Dog dog;
if ((dog = animal as Dog) != null) {
    // use dog
}
```

There are merits with the above syntax (which is close to the requested syntax) because:

1. Using `dog` *outside* the `if` will result in a compile error as it is not assigned a value elsewhere. (That is, *don't* assign `dog` elsewhere.)
2. This approach can also be expanded nicely to `if/else if/...` (There are only as many `as` as required to select an appropriate branch; *this the big case* where I write it in this form when I must.)
3. Avoids duplication of `is/as`. (But also done with `Dog dog = ...` form.)
4. Is no different than "idiomatic while". (Just don't get carried away: keep the conditional in a consistent form and and simple.)

To truly isolate `dog` from the rest of the world a new block can be used:

```
{
  Dog dog = ...; // or assign in `if` as per above
}
Bite(dog); // oops! can't access dog from above
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Point #1 that you offer is the first thing that came to my mind.  Declare the variable but only assign in the if.  The variable then can't be referenced from outside the if without a compiler error - perfect!

Answer (score 4):

With C# 9.0 and .NET 5.0 you can write it using **as** like that:

```
Animal animal;
if (animal as Dog is not null and Dog dog)
{
    //You can get here only if animal is of type Dog and you can use dog variable only
    //in this scope
}
```

It is because the **animal as Dog** in if statement produces the same result as:

```
animal is Dog ? (Dog)(animal) : (Dog)null
```

then **is not null** part checks if the result of above statement isn't null. Only if this statement is true it creates variable of type Dog dog, which can't be null.

This feature came to C# 9.0 with Pattern Combinators, you can read more about that right here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/patterns3#pattern-combinators

Answer (score 4):

Another late entry:

```
if (animal is Dog dog) 
{ 
    dog.Name="Fido"; 
}
else if (animal is Cat cat)
{
    cat.Name="Bast";
}
```

Comment: I ran into this syntax in some code this morning and was unfamiliar with it. On one PC it looks OK. On another, the declared variable, like "dog" or "cat" in your example, has a squiggly red line and the code does not compile.... Can you point to where the C# documentation covers this feature?

Answer (score 3):

Here's some additional dirty code (not as dirty as Jon's, though :-)) dependent on modifying the base class.  I think it captures the intent while perhaps missing the point:

```
class Animal
{
    public Animal() { Name = "animal";  }
    public List<Animal> IfIs<T>()
    {
        if(this is T)
            return new List<Animal>{this};
        else
            return new List<Animal>();
    }
    public string Name;
}

class Dog : Animal
{
    public Dog() { Name = "dog";  }
    public string Bark { get { return "ruff"; } }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var animal = new Animal();

        foreach(Dog dog in animal.IfIs<Dog>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dog.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(dog.Bark);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have to do multiple such as-ifs one after one (and using polymorphism is not an option), consider using a [SwitchOnType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298976/c-is-there-a-better-alternative-than-this-to-switch-on-type) construct.

Answer (score 1):

IDK if this helps anybody but you can always try to use a TryParse to assign your variable. Here is an example:

```
if (int.TryParse(Add(Value1, Value2).ToString(), out total))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I was able to parse your value to: " + total);
        } else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Couldn't Parse Value");
        }


        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static int Add(int value1, int value2)
    {
        return value1 + value2;
    }
```

The *total* variable would be declared before your if statement.

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like that

//Declare variable 
bool temp= false;

```
 if (previousRows.Count > 0 || (temp= GetAnyThing()))
                                    {
                                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Al little experimentation shows that we can use assignment in an if statement

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    bool f = false;
    if (f = Tru())
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("True");
    }
    if (f = Tru(false))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("False");
    }
}

private static bool Tru(bool t = true) => t ? true : false;
```

[image]

As far as any potential side effects or "Evil", I can't think of any, although I am sure somebody can.  Comments welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**With C# 7**'s [Pattern Matching](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/new-features-in-c-7-0/) you can now do things like:

```
if (returnsString() is string msg) {
  Console.WriteLine(msg);
}
```

This question was asked over 10 years ago now so almost all the other answers are outdated/wrong

Answer (score 0):

Another EVIL solution with extension methods :)

```
public class Tester
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        Animal a = new Animal();

        //nothing is printed
        foreach (Dog d in a.Each<Dog>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d.Name);
        }

        Dog dd = new Dog();

        //dog ID is printed
        foreach (Dog dog in dd.Each<Dog>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dog.ID);
        }
    }
}

public class Animal
{
    public Animal()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Animal constructued:" + this.ID);
    }

    private string _id { get; set; }

    public string ID { get { return _id ?? (_id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString());} }

    public bool IsAlive { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : Animal 
{
    public Dog() : base() { }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Each<T>(this object Source)
        where T : class
    {
        T t = Source as T;

        if (t == null)
            yield break;

        yield return t;
    }
}
```

I personally prefer the clean way:

```
Dog dog = animal as Dog;

if (dog != null)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An if statement won't allow that, but a for loop will.

e.g.

```
for (Dog dog = animal as Dog; dog != null; dog = null)
{
    dog.Name;    
    ... 
}
```

In case the way it works is not immediately obvious then here is a step by step explanation of the process:

- Variable dog is created as type dog and assigned the variable animal
  that is cast to Dog.
- If the assignment fails then dog is null, which prevents the contents
  of the for loop from running, because it is immediately broken out
  of.
- If the assignment succeeds then the for loop runs through the
  iteration.
- At the end of the iteration, the dog variable is assigned a value of 
  null, which breaks out of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
using(Dog dog = animal as Dog)
{
    if(dog != null)
    {
        dog.Name;    
        ... 

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm super duper late to the party, but I figured I'd post my own workaround to this dilemma since I haven't seen it on here yet (or anywhere for that matter).

```
/// <summary>
/// IAble exists solely to give ALL other Interfaces that inherit IAble the TryAs() extension method
/// </summary>
public interface IAble { }

public static class IAbleExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Attempt to cast as T returning true and out-ing the cast if successful, otherwise returning false and out-ing null
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="able"></param>
    /// <param name="result"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool TryAs<T>(this IAble able, out T result) where T : class
    {
        if (able is T)
        {
            result = able as T;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attempt to cast as T returning true and out-ing the cast if successful, otherwise returning false and out-ing null
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    /// <param name="result"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool TryAs<T>(this UnityEngine.Object obj, out T result) where T : class
    {
        if (obj is T)
        {
            result = obj as T;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

With this, you can do things such as:

```
if (animal.TryAs(out Dog dog))
{
    //Do Dog stuff here because animal is a Dog
}
else
{
    //Cast failed! animal is not a dog
}
```

IMPORTANT NOTE: If you want to use TryAs() using an Interface, you MUST have that interface inheriting IAble.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

There is workaround, I give you a little bit another example, you have a method which returns string Id, than if statement:

```
var userId = GetUserId();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
{ 
    //logic
}
```

you might be expected syntax like this, which isn't work:

```
if (string userId = GetUserId() && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
{
    //logic
}
```

But now, you can achieve the same result with:

```
if (GetUserId() is string userId && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
{ 
    //logic
}
```

In **your example** you can do of course:

```
if(animal is Dog dog)
{
    //logic
}
```

**but it find be usefull to consider using a method**

```
var animal = GetAnimal();

if (animal is Dog)
{
    //logic
}
```

and finally you can rewrite it to:

```
if(GetAnimal() is Dog dog)
{
    //logic
}
```