# Is there are way to combine "is" and "as" in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - Assignment in an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113347/c-assignment-in-an-if-statement)

I find my myself doing the following multiple time

```
if (e.row.FindControl("myLiteral") is Literal)
{
    (e.row.FindControl("myLiteral") as Literal).Text = "textData";
}
```

Is there way to replace the "if" part and simplify the setter:

```
(e.row.FindControl("myLiteral") <some operator that combines is and as> .text = "textData";
```

EDIT:
I should have mentioned this before-
I want to remove the 'if' entirely.
"some operator " should do this internally and set the ".text" only if e.row.FindControl is a literal

Comment: `as` already does an `is` for you and returns null if something `is` not a certain type.

Comment: heh, MS heard me  - for future Reference:
(e.row.FindControl("myLiteral"))??.text =="TextData";

Answer (score 6):

Normally I wouldn't combine them like that to start with - I'd *either* use a cast *or* I'd use `as` and a null check:

```
Literal literal = e.row.FindControl("myLiteral") as Literal;
if (literal != null)
{
    literal.Text = "textData";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in way to do this.  However you could author an extension method which gives you this capability

```
public static void AsType<T>(object o, Action<T> action) where T : class
{
    var value = o as T;
    if (value != null)
    {
        action(value);
    }
}
```

You could then write

```
e.row.FindControl("myLiteral").AsType<Literal>(l => l.Text = "textData");
```

Answer (score 1):

the as operator already does an is. If the cast succeed it returns the casted value, otherwise it returns null.

```
Literal lit = e.row.FindControl("myLiteral") as Literal;
if (lit != null)
{
    lit.Text = "textData";
}
```

or

```
if (e.row.FindControl("myLiteral") is Literal)
{
    Literal lit = (Literal)e.row.FindControl("myLiteral");
    lit.Text = "textData";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A check using `is` is typically followed by a cast:

```
if (e.row.FindControl("myLiteral") is Literal)
{
    ((Literal)e.row.FindControl("myLiteral")).Text = "textData";
}
```

Whereas `as` functions as such a check that returns either a successfully cast instance or `null` to the assigned variable, which you can then check for `null` (See [@Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477790/is-there-are-way-to-combine-is-and-as-in-c/7477816#7477816)).

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
var literal = e.row.FindControl("myLiteral") as Literal;
if (literal != null)
{
    literal.Text = "textData";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use `as` more like this (the standard usage):

```
Literal lit = e.row.FindControl("myLiteral") as Literal;
if (lit != null) {
  lit.Text = "textData";
}
```

If you're using .Net 3.5 or greater you could create an extension method to handle this (kind of):

```
internal static class Extensions {
  internal static void SetTextLiteral(this Control c, string text) {
    Literal lit = c as Literal;
    if (lit != null)
      lit.Text = text;
  }
}

void Sample() {
  e.row.FindControl("myLiteral").SetTextLiteral("textData");
}
```