# Linq to SQL: Dynamic insert during an update to another entity

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am using Linq to SQL and have a scenario in which I want to insert into a table whenever a specific record is updated.

So lets say I have `Table1` and `Table2`, whenever a record in `Table1` is updated I want to insert a new record into `Table2`.

Currently I have working code that allows me to update a couple of fields in `Table1` whenever it is updated, this has been achieved by creating a partial method for the `UpdateTable1` function, like so:

```
partial void UpdateTable1(Table1 instance)
{
   //update some fields
   this.ExecuteDynamicUpdate(instance);
}
```

This works great, and is so useful that I want to use it to ensure the new record is always created in `Table2` when `Table1` is updated. This is mostly for logging purposes by the way.

So this is what I tried to do next:

```
partial void UpdateTable1(Table1 instance)
{
   //update some fields
   this.ExecuteDynamicUpdate(instance);
   this.ExecuteDynamicInsert(instance.ConvertToTable2());
}
```

(I am using an extension method here to create a Table2 record based on the Table1 instance)

The problem is I am getting the following error:

> The operation cannot be performed for the entity because it is not
>   being change tracked.

Any ideas how I can make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget my unreliable workaround (see edit history if you must), I have found a much more reliable way to get this done!

Firstly, forget about using partial methods for this (e.g. `UpdateTable1` in the question) this do not work so well unless you are modifying the data for the instance record only. So I have keep these partial methods only for my need to update the related fields in the instance.

The way to do this is to override the `SubmitChanges` method in your partial `DataContext` class. This will allow insert/update/remove of any table records before you allow the default `SubmitChanges` to process (and thus lock-out this functionality).

Inside the override you can access the current `DataContext` change set using `this.GetChangeSet()`, from this you can loop all changes and perform any additional table work needed (e.g. add log records).

For the example below, lets assume I have a standard database table called `Table1` and I have a matching log table called `Table1Log`, I want to record any changes made to `Table1` inside of `Table1Log` so the log table contains all the same fields as the original but extends that to store a `DateTime` (time of change) and a `LogType` (i.e. Add/Edit/Delete).

Here is the important parts of my final code:

```
partial class MyDataContext
{

    public override void SubmitChanges(System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode failureMode)
    {

        var set = this.GetChangeSet();//get a list of all pending changes

        foreach (var item in set.Inserts)
        {
            AddLog(item, LogType.Add);
        }
        foreach (var item in set.Updates)
        {
            AddLog(item, LogType.Edit);
        }
        foreach (var item in set.Deletes)
        {
            AddLog(item, LogType.Delete);
        }

        base.SubmitChanges(failureMode);//allow the DataContext to perform it's default work (including your new log changes)

    }

    public void AddLog(object item, LogType logType)
    {

        //some painful type testing, so feel free to refactor this as you wish
        if(item is Table1)
        {
           var log = (item as Table1).ToLog(logType);//ToLog() is an extension method (one for each type)
           this.Table1_Logs.InsertOnSubmit(log);//add the log record ready to be submitted
        }
        else if(item is Table2)
        {
           //same again
        }
        //...repeat for each table class type

    }

}
```

**NOTE**: An alternative to the if/else type testing can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/299120/838807). I actually used this in my code and it works very nicely, I doubt there is a performance benefit but when you need to switch 50+ types it does help to keep things a bit more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for inserting, you really only have two options.  well, 3 actually.

You can add a trigger to the database.  We use this for change tracking where I work.  We have an update trigger that inserts a records with the changes.  It's effective, and easy.

If you want to use LINQ to SQL your only options are to insert the table as you have specified, i.e. `db.Table2s.InsertOnSubmit(...)` and then submit the changes.

The other option, assuming you have a foreign key relationship between your log table and your  entity is to assign that entity relationship via LINQ to SQL, then you can simply insert your log entity, without a reference to the data context.

```
partial void UpdateEntity(Entity instance)
{
    instance.Logs.Add(instance.createLogEntry());
}
```

When done this way, you will not need a reference to the data context, however depending on your situation this may not be an option.

Comment: Triggers are no good due to the extra data I need to log which comes from the system. The triggers wont be able to work this out. Your options involving relationships had already occurred to me, however I tried this (just like you posted) and the code ran fine but there was no new log record afterwards - have you actually seen this working?

Comment: I have seen the entity method working.  It basically depends on when you call it.  If you call it before calling `DataContext.SubmitChanges()` then it should work, as adding in to an entity set is analogous to calling `log.MyForeignKeyId = x; db.Logs.InsertOnSubmit(x);` however if it is called AFTER your initial call to `db.SubmitChanges()` then it will not be added, you would have to call `SubmitChanges` again.

Comment: Worked it out! See my answer if you are interested ;)