# Selecting property values from IEnumerable<t> using an expression list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I want to create a MVC helper where users can pass in a collection of expressions and the collection to pull those values from. This will create a table with the column Names and then a list of the values for those columns.

```
public class ColumnDefinition<T> where T: class 
{
        public Expression<Func<T,object>> Property { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string DefaultValue { get; set; }       
        public bool IsVisisble { get; set; }
        public string CssClass { get; set; }
}
```

So the helper might look like this:

```
public static IHtmlString ToTable<T>(this HtmlHelper helper, IEnumerable<T> list, IEnumerable<ColumnDefinition<T>> columnDefs) where T: class
{
    // ....
}
```

I know how to get the Property name from the `Expression<Func<T,object>>`, but not sure how to write the select statement for the list. This should work to get the values:

```
var someList= list.Select(() => columnDefs.Select(c => c.Property)).ToList();
```

I am trying to figure out how to Line up the Name with the value. So an example might be this:

```
var colDef = new List<ColumnDefinition<Foo>>()
            {
                new ColumnDefinition<Foo>()
                {
                    Property = f => f.Id,
                    DisplayName = "Foo"
                },
                new ColumnDefinition<Foo>()
                {
                    Property = f => f.Bar.Name,                    
                }
            }
```

So when that set of column definitions gets passed into the helper, I'd like to Get all the property names unless the `DisplayName` is present (i understand how to get the names) then I want to write the data for each one of those column definitions.

**Update**

So I have this so far:

```
public static class DataTablesHelper
    {
        public static DataTableModel GnerateColumns<T>(IEnumerable<T> list,
            IEnumerable<ColumnDefinition<T>> columnDefinitions) where T: class
        {
            foreach (var o in list)
            {
                var newList = GetInfo(o, columnDefinitions.ToList());
            }

            return new DataTableModel();
        }

        private static List<string> GetInfo<T>(T source, IEnumerable<ColumnDefinition<T>> columnDefinitions) where T : class
        {
            return columnDefinitions.Select(columnDefinition => columnDefinition.Property(source).ToString()).ToList();
        }
    }




    public class ColumnDefinition<T> where T: class 
    {
        public Func<T,object> Property { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string SortValue { get; set; }
        public bool IsVisisble { get; set; }
        public string CssClass { get; set; }

    }
```

This seems to work on getting the values and I can grab the Property names later. Ideally, it would be nice to pass in a string formatter to format the output.

**Update 2**

So, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298976/c-sharp-is-there-a-better-alternative-than-this-to-switch-on-type) technique which has been part of my core library now for some time, I came up with this to allow for simple formatting:

```
private static List<string> GetInfo<T>(T source, IEnumerable<ColumnDefinition<T>> columnDefinitions) where T : class
        {
            var listValues = new List<string>();
            foreach (var columnDefinition in columnDefinitions.ToList())
            {
                var prop = columnDefinition.Property(source);
                var definition = columnDefinition;
                TypeSwitch.Do(prop, TypeSwitch.Case<DateTime>(p => listValues.Add(p.ToString(definition.Format))),
                    TypeSwitch.Default(() => listValues.Add(prop.ToString())));
            }

            return listValues;
        }
```

I added a string that will house the formatter.

```
public class ColumnDefinition<T> where T: class 
    {
        public Func<T,object> Property { get; set; }
        public string Format { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string SortValue { get; set; }
        public bool IsVisisble { get; set; }
        public string CssClass { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Can they not just be `Func<>` delegates? What is your reason for using expressions?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, If I need to get the Name of the property wouldn't it need to be an expression? So, if DisplayName is null or empty, I could pull the property name?