# C# - Get switch value if in default case

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Help please, I have this case:

```
switch(MyFoo()){
    case 0: //...
        break;
    case 1: //...
        break;
    case 2: //...
        break;
    default:
        // <HERE>
        break;
}
```

As you can see the switch gets the value directly from a method without saving it as a variable.

Is it possible to get which value fires the `default` case? 
For example if `MyFoo()` returns 7, how can I get that value?

I want to avoid to save the method result as a variable, is there a way to get the switch value from inside a case? Something like this:

```
default:
    this.SwitchValue // <<--
    break;
```

Thank you for reading,
~Saba

Comment: "I want to avoid to save the method result as a variable" - why?

Comment: If you call MyFoo() again, will it return the same value?

Comment: "I want to avoid to save the method result as a variable" - There is no reason not to. It's on the stack anyway.

Comment: Your approach to me, seems like poor architecture and design.

Comment: This is a good `can the language do that` question, because it can't do that and so it is obviously not documented. Keep a trace about it is a job for SO.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the switch value from inside a case?

The only (proper) way is actually to store the result of `MyFoo()` in a variable.

```
var fooResult = MyFoo();
switch (fooResult)
{
    case 0:
        ...
        break;
    ...
    default:
        handleOthersCase(fooResult);
        break;
}
```

This code is readable and understandable and have no extra cost (As @SheldonNeilson says: It's on the stack anyway).

Also, the MSDN first example about [switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/06tc147t.aspx) totally look like this. You can also find informations int the [language specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa664749.aspx).

You also can make your own **switch** based on a [dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but the only advantage I see is that you can use it for complex *cases* (any kind of object instead of string/int/...). Performance is a drawback.

It may look like this:

```
public class MySwitch<T> : Dictionary<T, Action<T>>
{
    private Action<T> _defaultAction;

    public void TryInvoke(T value)
    {
        Action<T> action;
        if (TryGetValue(value, out action))
        {
            action(value);
        }
        else
        {
            var defaultAction = _defaultAction;
            if (defaultAction != null)
            {
                defaultAction(value);
            }
        }
    }

    public void SetDefault(Action<T> defaultAction)
    {
        _defaultAction = defaultAction;
    }
}
```

And be used like this:

```
var mySwitch = new MySwitch<int>();

mySwitch.Add(1, i => Console.WriteLine("one"));                             // print "one"
mySwitch.Add(2, i => Console.WriteLine("two"));                             // print "two"
mySwitch.SetDefault(i => Console.WriteLine("With the digits: {0}", i));     // print any other value with digits.

mySwitch.TryInvoke(42);                                                     // Output: "With the digits: 42"
```

Or based on [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10025398/361177), this:

```
public class MySwitch2<T>
{
    private readonly T _input;

    private bool _done = false;

    private MySwitch2(T input)
    {
        _input = input;
    }

    public MySwitch2<T> On(T input)
    {
        return new MySwitch2<T>(input);
    }

    public MySwitch2<T> Case(T caseValue, Action<T> action)
    {
        if (!_done && Equals(_input, caseValue))
        {
            _done = true;
            action(_input);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void Default(Action<T> action)
    {
        if (!_done)
        {
            action(_input);
        }
    }
}
```

Can be used like that:

```
MySwitch2<int>.On(42)
    .Case(1, i => Console.WriteLine("one"))
    .Case(2, i => Console.WriteLine("two"))
    .Default(i => Console.WriteLine("With the digits: {0}", i));
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be nicer if you could do the following so that fooResult is only visible in the scope of the switch block?

switch (var fooResult = MyFoo())
{
    case 0:
        ...
        break;
    ...
    default:
        handleOthersCase(fooResult);
        break;
}

Comment: ...if you agree, please vote at https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/9578766-define-variable-in-switch

Comment: The problem is just that a `goto case` statement that refers to an undeclared case and therefore will go to the `default` will not pass the case label value because it's not the value of the case variable.

Answer (score 6):

I can't see a reason as well why to use it like that but may be a work around will be like this:

```
int x;
switch ( x = MyFoo())
{
    case 0: //...
        break;
    case 1: //...
        break;
    case 2: //...
        break;
    default:
        var s = x; // Access and play with x here
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, this isn't possible.
You can assign the value to variable inside switch, if you want to look like reinventing the wheel:

```
        int b;
        .....
        switch (b = MyFoo())
        {
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            default:
                //do smth with b
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible now.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#property-patterns

Example:

```
int? TryGetColumnIndex(string columnName)
    => GetValue(columnName)
    switch
    { var result when result > -1 => result, _ => new int?() };
```

result will capture the result of GetValue.

Even cooler, you can do propery checks.

i.e instead of when result > -1 you can even say when result.ToString().Length > 2 and such.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to save the result of `MyFoo()` as a variable.. But if you don't want to do that you could do:

```
switch(MyFoo()){
    case 0: //...
        break;
    case 1: //...
        break;
    case 2: //...
        break;
    default:
        this.SwitchCase = MyFoo();
        break;
}
```

Although I would advise against this and say save the value as a variable to save your program the extra work.

Saving the value of `MyFoo` as a variable becomes more important the more complex the example gets as the value of `MyFoo` could have changed between the switch and default case.

Also this will only work where `MyFoo` has no side-effects and obviously must always return the same value for any given parameter.

for example the following would work:

```
Private int MyFoo()
{
   return 3;
}
```

But the following would not:

```
private int MyFoo()
{
  Random r = new Random();
  return r.Next(5);
}
```

Comment: I don't think the edit here makes the answer any clearer, the concept of a pure function is clearer than the replacement text in my opinion.