# Polymorphism using switch statement

Tags: c#, inheritance, switch-statement, polymorphism

We have some document-types:

```
class Document
{
    public void virtual Print()
}

class PDF : Document
{
    public void override Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PDF Printed");
    }
}

class Excel : Document
{
    public void override Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Excel Printed");
    }
}
```

Suppose we have a list of documents (Document objects) and we call the virtual function Print() on all of them.

```
foreach(Document doc in DocumentsList)
{
    doc.Print();
}
```

I know Polymorphism is much sophisticated way of implementing it but ***can we really do the same using switch statement as well***? I had a long argument with a fellow on it and he says it's possible. Is it?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? It'd just be more annoying.

Comment: Everything is possible without polymorphism. But it will look awkward.

Comment: Looks like this post might have what you're looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298976/is-there-a-better-alternative-than-this-to-switch-on-type
But I agree with the others, polymorphism is almost certainly the preferred way to do it.

Comment: The usual answer to "possible" is "yes" with Turing-complete languages.

Comment: If anyone could read the question properly, I have already mentioned that Polymorphism is a SOPHISTICATED way. I find it ridiculous that question is being downvoted and answers which are just yes or no are voted up

Comment: Dont get offended. The problem is just that it is kind of hard to understand why you are in doubt whether this can be done with a switch statement. Why not? Maybe you have something in mind why it should not be possible, but thats not apparent from your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can always use a switch (or an if-else chain), asking for the type. You can keep document type information in your object, for example as an enum, and use it in a switch.

Why you shouldn't do that? Because you have to extend all these switches when you add a new derived type.

To avoid that, you can implement something more automatic: Have a list of pointers to functions (or delegates in C#) which you fill for each single object with the functions suitable for this particular object (for example, the `print` delegate would point to `print_pdf()` for PDF files and to `print_excel()` for excel files). And hey, there you have hand-crafted a poor man's polymorphism.

The sweet thing about polymorphism is that the code *using* a polymorphic object can be type agnostic. It does not know what precise type the object actually has, and does not want to know. The precise type may not have existed back when the code *handling* the object was written. All the detail information is *hidden within the type*  which is awesome for maintenance.

Comment: @tobi303 said the same, I think

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can, of course you can interrogate the member of the list on each iteration, and there are plenty of techniques that can achieve this (e.g attributes, internal Type field etc).

**In fact everything you do in C# you can also do in Assembler!** 
However I can hardly see any benefit of avoiding the advantages of OOP.

Answer (score 4):

Its a bit of a funny question, because the example using the switch is usually used to demonstrate how you usually dont want to do it.

Instead of using inheritance, you could have your document class like this:

```
class Doc {
    public: 
        enum DocType{PDF,EXCEL}
    private:
        DocType docType;
}
```

And then you simply use

```
switch (doc.getDocType()){
    ...etc...
}
```

However, there are several reasons why usually it is nicer to use inheritance. Imagine for example, you want to add another document type. Then not only you have to add another enum field, but (and here comes the big problem) you also would have to change every single switch statement in all code that is using your Document class. That is annoying and usually you do not want to do this.

Comment: Apologies for overlooking the last part of your answer (before I went offline).

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism is the way to go for this.  If you choose `switch` statement, you would need to use `Reflection` or `is` keyword to figure out which object's `Print()` you want to invoke.

Comment: Why do you need reflection? You neither need reflection nor `is` keyword.