# How to cast different types in a method of a derived class?

Tags: c#, interface, casting, dry, derived-class

I have a base class `BaseCollectionInspector` which has two derived classes: `ReactionCollectionInspector` and `ConditionCollectionInspector`.

The base class has this method:

```
protected override void AddItem(object obj) {
    AssetInfo assetInfo = (AssetInfo) obj;
    string assetName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(assetInfo.assetPath);
    var assetType = Type.GetType(typeof(BaseReaction).Namespace + "." + assetName + ", Assembly-CSharp");
    var newItem = (BaseReaction) collection.gameObject.AddComponent(assetType);
    newItem.showItem = false; // Hide script in inspector
    int index = collectionList.serializedProperty.arraySize++;

    collectionList.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index).objectReferenceValue = newItem;
    serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
}
```

The difference between the two derived types is that one holds a list of `BaseReaction` and the other `BaseCondition` which both has a `showItem` property.

They both would use the exact same `AddItem` method, except the casting on `assetType` and `newItem`.

I'm trying to learn C# properly and want to use the DRY principle even if it's easy to just copy the code. I think I might be able to use an Interface, but I'm not sure how I would set that up, since I want the method to be just in the base class, adapting for the correct sub class.

I also tried putting something like this in each of the derived classes, but I can't find a way to use that for casting in the base class method:

```
private Type itemType = typeof(BaseReaction);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `AddItem(object obj)` is *rarely* good idea... It's hard to say what would be better without usage sample but consider if simply strongly typed separate methods or generic method would work.

Comment: This is a Unity Editor class, that is called like `    dropdownMenu.AddItem(new GUIContent(menuPath), false, AddItem, new AssetInfo {assetPath = path});` and AddItem sends whatever you click on (that can be of any type) as a parameter. So I can't really change that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298976/is-there-a-better-alternative-than-this-to-switch-on-type maybe what you are looking for...

Comment: Thanks, I noticed other similar problems with the derived classes, so I might have to make them separate anyhow, like both have a list called `collection` but one is of `ReactionCollection` type and the other is `ConditionCollection`. I can't seem to cast them in the subclass, and the base class still knows what properties exist in them. :/

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked very well for me was:

- Create a base class `CollectionItem` that both `BaseReaction` and `BaseCondition` derived from, which had all properties that were similar
- Create a base class `BaseCollection` that both `ReactionCollection` and `ConditionCollection` derived from, which had all properties that were similar

This way I could just reference the base classes `CollectionItem` and `BaseCollection` in the `BaseCollectionInspector`, and set all methods that I want to be unique for the derived inspectors to `abstract`

I'm sure this is pretty specific to what I was working with, but the main point is that it's possible, you just need to find the common parts of similar classes, and make a parent class of it.

Thanks for your help here though :)

*PS: I really love C# and realize how confusing PHP is to work with no strict typing of anything, even if I've worked in it for 20 years or so :)*