# C# - Which is the best alternative to ‘switch on type’?

Tags: c#, performance, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - Is there a better alternative than this to ‘switch on type’?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298976/c-sharp-is-there-a-better-alternative-than-this-to-switch-on-type)

1.)
http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/411739-switch-objectGetType-/?CommentID=411995

2.)
http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2008/05/16/switching-on-types.aspx

3.)
Or is there an even better way....?

Please reflect both on speed and ease of reading the code.

Comment: see also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156467/switch-pattern-matching-idea
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252186/switch-case-on-type-c-sharp
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542793/how-to-use-switch-case-on-a-type
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478464/c-sharp-switch-on-type
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298976/c-sharp-is-there-a-better-alternative-than-this-to-switch-on-type

Comment: and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94305/what-is-quicker-switch-on-string-or-elseif-on-type
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304815/why-is-this-switch-on-type-case-considered-confusing
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947343/how-to-switch-between-possible-type-of-an-object
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115028/best-way-to-switch-behavior-based-on-type

Answer (score 1):

Of all suggested I prefer second option. Generally, I prefer [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) over switching on `Type`s.