# How to switch between "possible" type of an object?

Tags: c#, .net, types, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - Is there a better alternative than this to ‘switch on type’?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298976/c-sharp-is-there-a-better-alternative-than-this-to-switch-on-type)

My company legacy code has something as follow

```
public override Uri GetUri(object obj)
{
    if ((obj is Entry) || (obj is EntryComment))
    {
        //
    }
    if (obj is Blog)
    {
        //
    }

    // if obj is blah blah blah
}
```

This method is just ugly. I want to refactor it, but I don't know a technique to iterate over "possible" types that obj can be.

How can I refactor this?

Thank you.

Comment: I added the region directive to demonstrate how ugly the code is :-s

Comment: Could you move the code inside the if-statement blocks into the types themselves? That way your method would just be: `return obj.Uri;`.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen, +1 for your comment.

Comment: see also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156467/switch-pattern-matching-idea
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252186/switch-case-on-type-c-sharp
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542793/how-to-use-switch-case-on-a-type
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478464/c-sharp-switch-on-type
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298976/c-sharp-is-there-a-better-alternative-than-this-to-switch-on-type

Comment: and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94305/what-is-quicker-switch-on-string-or-elseif-on-type
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304815/why-is-this-switch-on-type-case-considered-confusing
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115028/best-way-to-switch-behavior-based-on-type
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551773/c-sharp-which-is-the-best-alternative-to-switch-on-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also refactor this with interfaces

```
public interface IHasUri
{
   public Uri GetUri();
}
```

and implement this interface in all you hierarchy. Than you can use

```
public Uri GetUri(object obj)
{
    IHasUri hasUri = obj as IHasUri;
    if(hasUri != null)
      Uri uri = hasUri.GetUri();

    // bla bla bla 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A couple of options:

- If you're using C# 4, you could use dynamic typing, and split the method into a number of overloads:

  ```
  public Uri GetUri(dynamic obj)
  {
      return GetUriImpl(obj);
  }

  private Uri GetUriImpl(Entry entry)
  {
      ...
  }

  private Uri GetUriImpl(EntryComment comment)
  {
      ...
  }
  ```

  In this case you'd probably want some sort of "backstop" method in case it's not a known type.
- You could create a `Dictionary<Type, Func<object, Uri>>`:

  ```
  private static Dictionary<Type, Func<object, Uri>> UriProviders = 
      new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, Uri>> {   
      { typeof(Entry), value => ... },
      { typeof(EntryComment), value => ... },
      { typeof(Blog), value => ... },
  };
  ```

  and then:

  ```
  public Uri GetUri(object obj)
  {
      Func<object, Uri> provider;
      if (!UriProviders.TryGetValue(obj.GetType(), out provider))
      {
          // Handle unknown type case
      }
      return provider(obj);
  }
  ```

  Note that this *won't* cover the case where you receive a subtype of `Entry` etc.

Neither of these are particularly nice, mind you... I suspect a higher level redesign may be preferable.

Comment: +1, Only answer that actually shows how to do it and doesn't break Open/Closed principle

Answer (score 1):

I think Lasse V. Karlsen has the right of it in his comments, a redesign is more appropriate perhaps

You could create an interface like Stecya suggests

```
public interface IUriAccessible { //or some sort of a more descriptive name
    Uri Url {get;}
}
```

and then for each object that you care for, eg `Entry`, you could

```
public class Entry:IUriAccessible {
    //... other code here
    public Uri Url {
        get {
            //return uri here
        }
    }
}
```

and now you can just call it on the object

```
var entry = new Entry();
var uri = entry.Url;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `List<Type>()` with all types you want to check for and iterate that list. but I don't think that makes the code faster.

Comment: I don't want "Faster" code, but "more readable" code :). The problem is, the processing code for each type is not the same, so I don't think List<Type> is suitable. Switch is more suitable choice

Answer (score 0):

You can't `switch-case` types.

> A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type