# C# Switch on Object Type at Runtime

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `List<object>`. I want to loop over the list and print the values out in a more friendly manner than just `o.ToString()` in case some of the objects are booleans, or datetimes, etc.

How would you structure a function that I can call like `MyToString(o)` and return a string formatted correctly (specified by me) for its actual type?

Comment: There are _a lot_ of types, which do you intend to support?

Comment: Maybe create a `Dictionary<Type,Func<Object, String>>`.

Comment: You can't switch on Type, but there are some workarounds, as per this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298976/c-is-there-a-better-alternative-than-this-to-switch-on-type you could work that solution into a helper class.

Comment: Do you mean something like o.GetType().ToString()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [dynamic keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) for this with .NET 4.0, since you're dealing with built in types. Otherwise, you'd use polymorphism for this.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<object> stuff = new List<object> { DateTime.Now, true, 666 };
        foreach (object o in stuff)
        {
            dynamic d = o;
            Print(d);
        }
    }

    private static void Print(DateTime d)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm a date"); //replace with your actual implementation
    }

    private static void Print(bool b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm a bool");
    }

    private static void Print(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm an int");
    }
}
```

Prints out:

```
I'm a date
I'm a bool
I'm an int
```

Comment: How would the OP use polymorphism with primitive types such as bool ?

Comment: That's my exact point, you don't, unless you want to inherit from `System.Boolean` for example.

Comment: I'm confused: When you write "Otherwise use polymorphism", you mean "if .NET < 4", right?

Comment: By otherwise, I mean when you're not dealing with built in types. I agree my wording is a bit confusing.

Comment: dynamic has a non-zero cost in terms of performance, if you're going to use it in a large list it has to be taken in account.

Answer (score 1):

that depends on how important the design will be:

- if statements or switch-statement on o.GetType()/o.GetType().Name
- implementing a kind of IShow-Interface (with a method void Show(object o) and using a Dictionary to map types to implementations of this interface and just using

  ```
  if (TryGetValue(o.GetType, out show)) show.Show(o);
  ```
- just stick to it and let the objects tell the tale (override ToString) ... yes you don't want this but IMHO this *is* the best way to do this

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider overriding ToString() in a more friendly way?

Comment: So, he's going to create MyBooleans, MyIntegers, MyDates, etc? if they were his own classes then this would be totally applicable, and although this would work, it just seems a bit painful to subclass a bunch of builtin types just to provide .ToString() overrides. Reasonable answer, but personally I don't think I could do that and be happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example with comments. It uses a generic Dictionary of Type and Lambda Func.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        // a custom class
        public class MyPerson
        {
            public string FN { get; set; }
            public string LN { get; set; }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // your prebuilt dictionary of Types to Lambda expressions to get a string
            Dictionary<Type, Func<object, String>> MyToStringLookup = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, string>>()
            {

                {typeof(String), new Func<Object, String>( obj => obj.ToString() )},
                {typeof(DateTime), new Func<Object, String>( obj => ((DateTime)obj).ToString("d") )},
                {typeof(MyPerson), new Func<Object, String>( obj => (obj as MyPerson).LN )},
            };
            // your list of objects
            List<Object> MyObjects = new List<Object>()
            {
                "abc123",
                DateTime.Now,
                new MyPerson(){ FN = "Bob", LN = "Smith"}
            };
            // how you traverse the list of objects and run the custom ToString
            foreach (var obj in MyObjects)
                if (MyToStringLookup.ContainsKey(obj.GetType()))
                    System.Console.WriteLine(MyToStringLookup[obj.GetType()](obj));
                else // default if the object doesnt exist in your dictionary
                    System.Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is an equivalent to if-else-if structure. switch does not allow switch on type, because the switch structure needs an enumerable ensemble with mutually exclusive values (and an object can be of several types).

Edit for Abbas comment:

GetType().Name is valid but will lead you to potential errors in this context, because it can return a type you don't know. Even if an object is stored as a type A, GetType().Name can potentially return "B" if B inherits A. If you don't know B in the context of the method doing the switch (it could be a type from another library that inherits one of the current library, it could be a type that has been added after you wrote your method), you will miss it in your pseudo-typeswitch. If you write `if(obj is A)` though, you won't.

Example, if I write this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Displays ":)" if obj is a Foo
/// </summary>
public static void CaseType(object obj)
{
    switch(obj.GetType().Name)
    {
        case "Foo":
           MessageBox.Show(":)");
           break;
             default:
           MessageBox.Show(":(");
           break;
    }
}
```

The comment is a lie, because

```
public class Bar : Foo
{
}

public static void CaseTypeSpecialized()
{
     Foo obj = new Bar();
     CaseType(obj);
}
```

will display ":(".

It will work if you write

```
/// <summary>
/// Displays ":)" if obj is a Foo
/// </summary>
public static void CaseType(object obj)
{
    if (obj is "Foo")
    {
        MessageBox.Show(":)");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(":(");
    }
}
```

It's the *concept* of switch that is incompatible with non-mutually exclusive values. That's why you can get compilation **errors** when you switch on a Flags enum when the values are not exclusives.

Comment: You actually can use a switch statement, see my answer on how to use it! :)

Comment: Yes but no. I edited my answer to explain why I don't think it's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like this might get you on the way:

```
private static String MyToString(object o)
{
    var val = "";
    switch (o.GetType().Name)
    {
        case "Boolean": val = ((bool)o) ? "this is true" : "this is false"; break;
        case "DateTime": val = "The date is: " + ((DateTime)o); break;
        case "Int32": val = "The number-value is: " + (int)o; break;
    }
    return val;
}
```

Hope this helps! ;)

Comment: I'd add a default: case for val = o.ToString(), but this is a clean procedural solution.