# How to optimize the code below

Tags: c#, optimization

How can I optimize the below code, the below code contains an object array that might have different type of class objects. I would prefer to move to switch case instead of if...else... how could I do it.

```
object[] emailObjs;
for (int i = 0; i < emailObjs.Length; i++)
{
if (emailObjs[i] != null)
    {
       if (emailObjs[i] is Rfq)
       {

       }
       else if (emailObjs[i] is RfqBid)
       {

       }
       else if (emailObjs[i] is RfqProjManager)
       {

       }
    }
}
```

Comment: But your `else if`s don't do anything...

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7252205/67579

Comment: `Rfq`, `RfqBid` and `RfqProjManager` are related classes? Are they having inheritance relationship?

Comment: There is a new feature in C# 7.0: *Switch statements with patterns*, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/ . You could do `switch emailObjs[i] { case Rfq r: ... case RfqProjManager rpm: ... `

Comment: You can do it in C# 7.0.

Comment: which C# Version are you using?

Comment: If the order isn't important, you could use `foreach(var obj in emailObjs.OfType<Rfq>()) // do something`

Comment: This is a duplicate of at least tens of other questions, what did your research show? Also, in general, when you need this, that's a design smell. What exactly is this code supposed to do?

Comment: @william Van Onsem: I havent given the entire code

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: The classes are not related

Comment: @PawełSłowik:  we are using VS2010 so no chance of C#7 pattern matching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define for all 3 classes common interface with one method:

```
public interface IRfq
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class Rfq : IRfq
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class RfqBid : IRfq
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class RfqProjManager : IRfq
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

And you could do just one call in your for loop.

```
IRfq[] emailObjs;
for (int i = 0; i < emailObjs.Length; i++)
{
   emailObjs[i]?.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: _If_ they want to call `DoSomething()` on all objects and it doesn't already have a base class defining that method.

Answer (score 2):

Use [C# 7 pattern matching](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/) in a `switch` statement with a type check:

```
switch (emailObjs[i])
{
    case Rfq r:
        {
            // use r;
            break;
        }
    case RfqBid r:
        {
            // use r;
            break;
        }
}
```

Although this will compact your code significantly, performance-wise it wouldn't have much benefit over an bunch of `if` statements, like in your sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my try:

Rfq, RfqBid, and RfqProjManager implement the same interface. Let's call it IRfq.

```
interface
{
     void DoSomeWork();
}
```

Then, your for loop could be like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < emailObjs.Length; i++)
{
    if (emailObjs[i] != null && emailObjs is IRfq)
    {
           ((IRfq)emailObjs[i]).DoSomeWork();
    }
}
```

Is it possible with your design ?

Comment: _"Is it possible with your design?"_ - then post a comment first to ask that, instead of guessing in an answer.

Comment: Yes, I know, but that doesn't mean you should post answers instead... Anyway you now have 50 reputation.

Comment: Thanks for the advice (and for the reputation). I will do it better next time.